# Pushing external library to a git repository

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea

I am currently doing a project using Java on Intellij and imported some external libraries to write it. I need someone to run this project from another machine using version control. Unless, when opening the project from the other machine the code is showing some errors because the libraries that I used are note here.

PS: By looking over the Internet I saw that a lot of people are using Maven to do it but I cannot use it for my project.

Is there any way that I can "push" those libraries onto my git repository so another person can just clone my repo and the libraries at the same time?

Comment: you shouldn't. None of that is related to the project itself. Just add a readme with prerequisites. Why can't you use maven or gradle or ... ?

Comment: You can add libraries to your project in git if you really want to (make sure to mark them as binary!), but using something like Maven or Gradle is highly recommended.

Comment: It is a university project and my teacher told us not to use maven that is why i'm trying to find another way to do it

Comment: Yes, you *can* put your libraries in your git repository (for example under `lib/`) but for various reasons almost no one actually does that. But if you're not "allowed" to use Maven or any other build tool and want to avoid manual "download this from there" steps, then it's probably your best option. Alternatively: provide a shell script that builds your classes that also downloads the jar file from some central repository, if they are not present (and add the `lib/` directory to `.gitignore`).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Maven or Gradle is to include in your project a declarative approach which allows you to *declare* your dependencies, which are then downloaded from a central public referential.

If your "some external libraries" are purely private, then you need to set up a local (to your intranet) binary referential ([Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus-repository), [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/), ...), in order to replicate that.
That way, you would still be able to use Maven/Gradle.

Adding those libraries in a source referential like Git would not be considered as a "best practice".